# Get FVector from Blueprint tick function

Tags: c++, unreal-4, blueprints

In my BluePrint Tick function for my character, I have a FVector that always changes, and in my C++ component, I want to get this changing FVector and use it in my C++ Tick function, is that possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

To set this in C++, you need to create a UPROPERTY in your C++ code then write a function to set this property.

In your C++ header file:

```
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "FVectors")
FVector MyCPPVector;

UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "FVectors")
void SetFVector(FVector VectorIn);
```

And in your cpp file

```
void SetFVector(FVector VectorIn)
{
    MyCPPVector = VectorIn;
};
```

Now after you've set the FVector in your Blueprint, call the SetFVector function and plug the BP FVector output into the input of the function.

Comment: This is the correct and most concise solution